# How to solve the error " Trying to get property of non-object" - Slim 3 Framework PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

first, sorry for my english and , second my error is

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp64\www\projeto\app\OfertasVendor\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php
>   on line 9

The line 9 of ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php is:

```
$this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors',$_SESSION['errors']);
```

the complete code of ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php is

```
<?php
namespace OfertasVendor\Middleware;
class ValidationErrorsMiddleware extends Middleware{
    public function __invoke($req, $res, $next){        $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors',$_SESSION['errors']);
        //var_dump($_SESSION['errors']);
        //unset($_SESSION['errors']);
        var_dump('teste');
        $res = $next($req, $res);
        return $res;
    }
}
```

But, i have made the Middleware.php, i pass the container,
the code of Middleware:

```
namespace OfertasVendor\Middleware;
//use OfertasVendor\Controllers\DatabaseController;
class Middleware{
    protected $container;
    public function __contruct($container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

i just have to pass the container->view, but, the framework does not recognize the container...

I have made the Controller.php

```
namespace OfertasVendor\Controllers;
abstract class Controller{
    protected $container;
    public function __construct($container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public function __get($key){
        if($this->container->{$key}){
            return $this->container->{$key};
        }
    }
}
```

My app index.php have the Middleware

```
$app->add(new \OfertasVendor\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware($container));
```

Can you help me?

Comment: **line 9** Which line is line 9. Its not at all clear from the code you have pasted here

Comment: The line 9 is $this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors',$_SESSION['errors']);

Comment: Well one of those things you think are objects are not objects

Comment: they say that "view" not is a object, but i need the object... i use in the rest of code the view object and works, but in this file does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `var_dump($this->container);` and `die();`

If that's an object, try `var_dump($this->container->view);`, then `die();`

Basically, keep vardumping each step until you get to whatever is not an object. More often than nut something is `null`.

Comment: I do var_dump($this->container)  and returns NULL

Comment: when i do var_dump($this->container->view) returns  "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\projeto\app\OfertasVendor\Middleware\ValidationErrorsMiddleware.php on line 12"

Comment: But i need to use "$this->container->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('errors',$_SESSION['errors']);"

Comment: So, that's it, then, for some reason $this->container is NULL. That's not an object. Try vardumping $container in Middleware.php's constructor. Something is setting it to null somewhere. Keep going up the chain to see where it's happening.